# Обращение к объекту метода JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

у меня есть вот такой код:

```
mehod({
  form: '.form'
});
```

Как мне обратиться внутри method к form?

Comment: как определяется функция `method`?

Comment: function method() {}

Answer (score 2):

вот так

```
function method(a) {
 let form = а.form;     
}
```

либо

```
function method(a) {
 let {form} = а;
}

mehod({  form: '.form'
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что было нужно

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста